# Wordpress Custom post type slug rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I want to rewrite custom post type slug. I used this snippet. but not working.

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse247328_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse247328_register_post_type_args( $args ) {

    if ( 'stores' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'location';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not working" ? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Did you flush rewrite rules and such?

Comment: Url slug not updating .. old url was:  www.abc.ocm//stores/mo-ellisville/  after add this code url not updating . :(

Comment: You may need to use `unregister_post_type` then re-register it, then visit the Settings > Permalinks page to flush rewrite rules.

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules after changing the slug? `unregister_post_type` was only necessary before the `register_post_type_args` filter was introduced in v4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had to face a similar issue a while ago and got it resolved by following this [guide](http://www.ibenic.com/custom-wordpress-rewrite-rule-combine-taxonomy-post-type/).

Basically what you have to do is two functions 1) Custom WordPress Rewrite Rule and 2) Custom Post Type Link.

The Rewrite Rule function will make sure the custom slug for your CPT is handled properly throughout the site. And the second function will ensure that it displays the URL the way you want - you can also include taxonomy variables if you wish to. Anyway take a look at the article as it helped me a lot and I hope it helps you too as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just at the rewrite slug action in your custom post type code?

```
$rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'Your-new-slug',
        'with_front'            => true,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, it's obviously because of missing argument
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/
Just add `$post_type` as second param to your function

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse247328_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse247328_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'stores' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'location';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

One more thing, please set `WP_DEBUG` to true while working locally to see all the warnings.